Bulk insert data in to a oracle DB using spring JDBC

As part of test data setup, we need to insert around 200K records across few tables in a oracle database.
we have a spring based application which we are using to insert the records in database.

I have a method, which will take path of a file have INSERT queries and insert them in to database by batches. here is the sample code:
public void setupDB(String sqlFilePath, int batchSize, int threadCount) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
        List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        log.info("Started Processing File:{} at {}", sqlFilePath, LocalDateTime.now());

        try (var reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Path.of(sqlFilePath).toFile()))) {
            var batch = new ArrayList<String>();

            reader.lines().forEach(line -> {
                batch.add(line);
                if (batch.size() == batchSize) {
                    var batchCopy = List.copyOf(batch);
                    futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> repository.executeBatch(batchCopy), executorService));
                    batch.clear();
                }
            });

            if (!batch.isEmpty()) {
                var future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> repository.executeBatch(batch), executorService);
                futures.add(future);
            }
            log.info("Batches size: {}", futures.size());

            CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();

            log.info("Finished Processing SQL File at {}", LocalDateTime.now());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error seeding db", ex);
        } finally {
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }

Code to insert data into database:
@Retryable(backoff = @Backoff(delay = 15000, multiplier = 2, maxDelay = 300000), retryFor = CannotGetJdbcConnectionException.class)
    public void executeBatch(List<String> queries) {
        jdbcTemplate.execute((Connection connection) -> executeBatch(connection, queries));
    }

    private int[] executeBatch(Connection connection, List<String> insertQueries) throws SQLException {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        int[] results = new int[0];
        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            for (String query : insertQueries) {
                statement.addBatch(query);
            }
            results = statement.executeBatch();
            connection.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            connection.rollback();
            log.error("Error executing sql batch", ex);
        } finally {
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
        return results;
    }

Code to invoke the functions:
var setOneTasks = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            preparedLayerDataService.setupDB(sqlPath1, 500, 30);
        });

        var setTwoTasks = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            preparedLayerDataService.setupDB(sqlPath2, 500, 30);
        });

        CompletableFuture.allOf(setOneTasks, setTwoTasks).join();
        log.info("Completed loading data");
     

Statistics:

Questions:

Each Insert queries have about 45 columns and Insertion of 180K records is taking around 9 - 10 mins, are there any other approaches which will reduce the time to load the data.


If you're using Spring boot you can do it like this
You would add a data.sql in your resources file and that will be initisalised.

I don't want to  initialize that data for all the tests, but only for a specific set of tests, so i tried  initializing using the JDBC. are there any libraries or optimizations that i can use to make this process faster ?
